# React selector cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

I am trying to follow the react reducer/selector model, but the selector is being called before the reducer can finish populating the store.

In my reducer, I have a reducer set up so `case: FETCH_API_CATEGORIES_OK` will return below function:

```
function processCategories(state, action) {
    return {...state, categories: action.categories} 
}
```

In my selector, I map over state.categories (an array of objects) and do some additional logic processing on it (sorting, etc) and return `{...state, categories: sortedCategories}`. Naturally, I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` since the component using the selector does not have the categories yet until the async call finishes. What is the best way to defend against this?